# Python language in Ubuntu

Tags: software-development, python, ubuntu

I want to learn Python, but I don't know which good software I could use to do that. Furthermore, I'd like to take a good course to learn this language.

**Questions :**

1. Which good software could I use to do that?
2. What kind of good website (course) could I use to learn Python?

Comment: Have you seen the [Beginners' guide](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide)?

Comment: This is not a software recommendation question. It its about development of a learning plan.

Answer (score 0):

The best tools for learning Python are:

1. Python
2. Python
3. A text editor that you are happy with, ideally one that syntax highlights.
4. An internet connection to get to Stack Overflow, the forums, online learning material, etc.

Comment: "Online learning material"... What are you recommend?

Comment: Personally I like Python 101 & Dive Into Python for a beginner but https://github.com/revolunet/PythonBooks is well worth a look. There are also sites which set problems for you to solve, etc., the Python User Groups.

Answer (score 0):

For learning resources check out this [interactive tutorial](https://www.learnpython.org/), these are good due to there practical nature.

If you are like me and jump in at the deep end, try out [learn python the hard way](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/).

Finally, [this one](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/introduction-to-python-programming-in-ubuntu-linux) is Ubuntu specific, if that is your need.

For the actual coding, I recommend the default environment, call it with

`python`

in a terminal and get coding.

If you like a simple GUI, use a text editor, I like gedit (Ubuntu default), it has full syntax highlighting of files saved with the `.py` extension.

If you want a full IDE, check out [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu) on AskUbuntu, for a large list.